# border-collapse is not working in flying-saucer?

Tags: pdf-generation, flying-saucer

In flying-saucer, border-collapse is not working if I use fs-paginate-table for the same table.

Does anybody know any workaround on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use :

```
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Example:

```
table{-fs-table-paginate:paginate;}
td{border:1px solid red}
```

[image]

```
table{-fs-table-paginate:paginate;border-spacing:0}
td{border:1px solid red}
```

[image]

The result is not exactly the same (as the TD's borders don't merge), but it can be fixed by setting borders only on one side of the TD.

```
#t4{-fs-table-paginate:paginate;border-spacing:0}
#t4 td{border-width:0 1px 1px 0;border-color:red}
#t4 tr.firstrow td{border-top-width:1px}   /* Assuming first TR has class firstrow */
#t4 td.firstcol{border-left-width:1px}     /* Assuming first TD of each line has class firstcol */
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for that, it worked for me. I added a pic in the response in case it could clarify what I suggest.

Comment: Use `tr:first-child { border-top-width:1px;}` and `td:first-child:{border-left-width: 1px;}` instead of `firstrow` and `firstcol` classes.

Answer (score 0):

This css rule works for me:

```
table.bordered {
    border-collapse: collapse
}
table.bordered td, table.bord
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```